# jQuery.map() only finds elements with numeric IDs

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I'm storing table row orders server side so that users can arrange the rows as they see fit. When I load the page, I call this:

```
var items = $('#body').find('tr');

var order = [ <? echo $row_order; ?>];

var orderedItems = $.map(order, function(value) {
   return items.get(value);
});

$('#body').empty().html(orderedItems);
```

This works perfectly if the rows have integer IDs. It does not work if there are letters in the ID - the table is just emptied. Throwing a console.log() on the orderedItems variable, I see that it is also empty in this case. Is there a way to make it work with alphanumeric row IDs, or will I just have to change naming conventions?

EDIT

Here are two instances of the order variable, the first working, the second not:

```
var order = [ 1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21];

var order = [ view_42,edit_42,view_41,view_43];
```

Comment: Whats is the valid value of `[ <? echo $row_order; ?>]`?

Comment: jQuery map works only on JS arrays and returns arrays.

Comment: `.get()` expects the index of the items in the array, which is a numerical value that is the reason

Comment: what is the value in the `order`? is it the id of rows?

Comment: are those the element ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order is an array of element ids

```
var items = $('#body').find('tr');

var order = [ <? echo $row_order; ?> ];

var orderedItems = $.map(order, function (value) {
    //or return $('#' + value).get();
    return items.filter('#' + value).get();
});

$('#body').empty().html(orderedItems);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n1kucb8f/)

Comment: They are the IDs. However, non-numeric IDs give this error now: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableRowElement]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var orderedItems = $.map(order, function(value) {
   return items.filter('#' + value);
});
```